# Android - How to put an ongoing event on status bar but not on notification screen?

Tags: android, notifications

In my app I added an ongoing  notification. The notification has an icon on status bar, and more details in the notification area.

This image is from Google. This is the notification area:

[image: This image is from Google. This is the notification area]

I need that the icon on status bar will stay there always, but the user will be able to dismiss the notification in the notification screen so the user will stay only with the icon on status bar.
How can I do it?

My service code:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
   {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, startId);

        ...

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.myNotificationString))
            .setContentText(string1 + "  |  " + string2)
            .setLargeIcon(appIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + getCurrentIconNumber(),"drawable", getPackageName()));  // the icon changes every day

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 ,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(myRequestCode, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: sorry but for me it's not clear the issue

Comment: I edited. In short: Let's say I have an app that shows the users the battery status. The user want to see the battery status on the status bar, but he doesn't want to see it all the time as a notification in the notification area. So I want that the user will be able to dismiss the notification in the notification area but the icon on the status bar will not disappear.

Comment: like a alarm clock active notification? you can remove the notification that you have an alarm already set, but if you remove it, you will anyway always see the app icon in the status bar. Did I understand?

Comment: I think so.. If I understood you

Answer (score 0):

try to define `resultPendingIntent` like below

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 ,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
```

**EDIT 1**

```
   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
   {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, startId);

        ...

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.myNotificationString))
            .setContentText(string1 + "  |  " + string2)
            .setLargeIcon(appIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + getCurrentIconNumber(),"drawable", getPackageName()));  // the icon changes every day

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 ,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(myRequestCode, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: But I have " notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;" - isn't it enough? anyway it doesn't work because the user cannot dismiss the notification at all, it's sticky.

Comment: ok, I see. Then revert that change and make this change `notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;`

Comment: sorry, try this `notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;`, so remove the `|` in the assigment

Comment: sorry @TamarG, I edited my answer in order to be clearer, try the code at EDIT 1

Comment: I edited my code and I still cannot dismiss the notification at all.

Comment: did you put again `PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 ,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` ? maybe I'm not really understanding your issue

Comment: Yes. The notification cannot be dismissed at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118020/discussion-between-ddb-and-tamarg).